# Can I create javascript function from remote in arangodb

Tags: arangodb, foxx

I have a remote application where users writes queries for arangodb. I want a way to interact with arangodb from REST interface and create the scripts as javascript function. Is it possible?

For example:

script1
    arangodb.db.collection1.properties();

script2
    arangodb.db.collection2.properties();

So, I was hoping if I could push the these script as to reside as javascript function at arangodb. and later when I need to run these I could just somehow do a script1() or script2() rmeotely through REST interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is totally possible, just take a look at the built-in [Foxx Framework](https://docs.arangodb.com/Foxx/README.html).
To see some example code take a look at [aye-aye](https://github.com/arangodb/aye-aye) a simple ToDo application.
You can also checkout other foxx apps for that github user.

Foxx Apps can be uploaded during run-time of arangodb. No restarting necessary.

Comment: I ran through the example Foxx app. It seems that If I start the foxx app then I can not access the default ui (aardvark) which comes with the arangodb by default. Is there a possibility if I can have both? I just want to plugin my REST implementation along with the aardvark

Comment: yes, it's possible. If the two application's routes do not conflict (and they shouldn't for the two applications in question), then you can use both applications in parallel. You can also have more than two, just install them using different mount points.